# Excel script for ereasing text multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need help in excel with deleting text between "/" and "/" for example:
"Ms Smith / New York / company" 
After deleting:
"Ms Smith company"

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). Afterwards, please update your question with the `VBA` code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Even recording a macro is a way to start.

Comment: use `Replace`, you can read about it here (it's called `using Google`): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @ShaiRado Replace only works if you know the word in between. If it was a regex replace, then I can agree with you. But in this case it seems simple string functions works just as good as regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND("/";A1)-1)&RIGHT(A1;FIND("/";A1;FIND("/";A1)+1))
```

If the text is in A1...

EDIT; Just noticed I used ; instead of , as delimiter.
Bad habit from my excel...

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1)&RIGHT(A1,FIND("/",A1,FIND("/",A1)+1))
```

Comment: In my excel i need to use ; insted of ,
So it looks like this:
"ARKADIA / BIAŁYSTOK / BH."
"ARKADIA TOK / BH."
Almoust works well.

Comment: Yes.. Sorry I just noticed my error.. I forgot +1. Just a sec and I will update the answer

Comment: @sokol now the formula should look for the second "/" and not the first and get "Company" as it was supposed to...

Comment: i just checked the solution with find and replece and it works with "/*/", but your solution works as well! thanks!